# strftime in sqlite convert to postgres

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

I came across a function in sqlite that I need to convert to postgres syntax. It's `date(date, '-'||strftime('%w',date)||' days')`.

Can anyone help me convert this sqlite segment to postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This SQLite:

```
date(date, '-' || strftime('%w', date) || ' days')
```

Is, AFAIK, subtracting the day-in-the-week number days (i.e. 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, ...) from `date` and then converting the result back to a `date`; see the [date function reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for details.

I think the equivalent for PostgreSQL would be:

```
d - extract(dow from d)::int
```

where `d` is your date; subtracting an integer from a date subtracts that number of days. If `d` is a timestamp, then you might need to add some casting. There is [`date_trunc('week', 'd')`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) as well but that starts numbering the days from Monday so you'd be off by one with that.

---

Here's a quick breakdown of the SQLite with the `date` variable replaced by `d` to avoid confusion with the `date()` function:

```
date(d, '-' || strftime('%w', d) || ' days')
```

First of all, `||` is the standard SQL string concatenation operator. The [`strftime` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) is a general purpose date and time formatter that comes from [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html); the `%w` format specifier means "day of the week as a number with Sunday being day zero"; so the `strftime` call gives you 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, and so on up to 6 for Saturday. If `d` is a Tuesday, then the `strftime` call will yield 2 and the whole thing ends up as:

```
date(d, '-2 days')
```

The modifiers for the SQLite [`date` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) have various forms but `'-2 days'` means just what you'd think: subtract two days from `d`. The overall result is that you get `d` truncated to the week (where Sunday is considered to be the first day of the week).

On the PostgreSQL side:

```
d - extract(dow from d)::int
```

we can start with [`extract`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT); `extract` is used to extract specific parts of a date or time and `dow` means "day of the week as a number with Sunday being day zero". Sound familiar? Then the `::int` casts the DOW number to an integer and is needed because the DOW actually comes out as a double precision value and there is no operator defined for subtracting a double from a date in PostgreSQL; the cast can also be written in the standard form as `cast(x as int)`. When you subtract an integer from a date in PostgreSQL, you subtract that many days; you can be more explicit by saying things like `- interval '3 days'` but that would just add more noise in this case so I opted for simplicity. If it is Tuesday, then our PostgreSQL version looks like:

```
d - 2
```

and that's the same as:

```
d - interval '2 days'
```

And after the subtraction we'd be back on Sunday. There's also [`date_trunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) in PostgreSQL but that would truncate to Monday not Sunday.

Comment: can you take me through the logic of the sqlite statement and then the logic of the postgres? I'm having a difficult time following the reference.

Comment: @cfarm54: I added a bit of walk-through for you.

Answer (score 3):

Given a datetime format like "*Mar 12 18:07:22*"

### `psql` using `to_char`

PostgreSQL client using [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-formatting.html) function:

```
psql -c "SELECT to_char(time,'Mon DD HH24:MI:SS ') FROM mytable;"
```

In this example, the postgres column `__time__` is type `time_stamp`.

### `sqlite3` piped to `awk`.

SQLite using [`strftime`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function with the help of `awk`:

```
sqlite3 'SELECT strftime("%s", time, "localtime") FROM mytable;' \
  |  awk '{print strftime("%b %e %H:%M:%S",$1) }'
```

The printed format will be *Mar 12 18:07:22*. The sqlite column `__time__` was a `TEXT` type as ISO8601 strings.

Answer (score 2):

%w is the day of the week as a number from Sunday=0, same as Postgresql's DOW: `SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');` from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

The string operations ought to be pretty simple, but I haven't done Postgres for about 10 years.

[after more research]
The `||` operator, as I suspected, is string concatenation, from http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

[after installing sqlite and postgresql]
the sqlite function is calculating the Sunday preceding the given date:

```
sqlite> select date('now', '-'||strftime('%w','now')||' days');
2011-08-21
```

[mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) gave the final piece of the puzzle:

```
postgres=# select date 'now' - extract(dow from timestamp 'now')::int;
  ?column?  
------------
 2011-08-21
```

Comment: is there a replacement that you can suggest?