# convert sqlite to postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

Can someone help me convert this sqlite query to a postgres query?

```
SELECT count(*), count(*), date(date, '-'||strftime('%w',date)||' days') as date
FROM emails as m, contacts as me
WHERE datetime(date) > datetime('2010-08-25')
  and datetime(date) < datetime('2011-08-25')
  and (me.id = m.fr)
  and me.email like '%gmail.com%'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date asc
```

update, I found the answer:

```
select count(*), (m.date::date - extract(dow from m.date)::int) as dat
from emails as m join contacts as me on m.fr = me.id
where m.date > '2010-08-25'
  and m.date < '2011-08-25'
  and me.email like '%gmail.com%'
group by dat
order by dat
```

Comment: what type are you using for the date column in potsgres?

Comment: Are there really two `count(*)` or is that a typo?

Comment: There seems to be two `count(*)`, not sure why either. the date type is "timestamp with timezone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strftime` business was taken care of [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171561/strftime-in-sqlite-convert-to-postgres/7171851#7171851) so we only have to sort out the `datetime(...)` stuff here and compensate for `date` being a timestamp. And I'll switch to an explicit join condition (rather than the implicit one in the WHERE clause) while I'm here.

```
select count(*), count(*), m.date::date - extract(dow from m.date)::int as date
from emails as m join contacts as me on m.fr = me.id
where m.date > '2010-08-25'
  and m.date < '2011-08-25'
  and me.email like '%gmail.com%'
group by m.date
order by m.date asc
```

PostgreSQL can compare timestamps with ISO8601 date strings on its own so you don't need any casting or reformatting for the comparisons.

The two `count(*)` still look a bit funny to me but I don't know the context that the query is used in so the duplicates might make sense.

Comment: for some reason this isn't quite it. when you are saying `group by date` it doesn't really group it and add the count together.

Comment: @cfarm54: Do you have any sample data and the schemas? We have the `date` column, the `date` function, and the `date` alias; PostgreSQL and SQLite might be making different choices about which is meant in various situations.

Comment: sure the schema for `emails` is: `(id integer primary key autoincrement,
        fr int references contacts(id), subj text, date datetime, mid text unique,
        reply text references msgs(mid), multipart bool);`

the schema for `contacts` is: `(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name text, email text not null);
`. I am also getting confused with the term 'date'; between the method call and the variable, it's very confusing :P.

Comment: I added the table prefix to the various `date` column uses, see if that doesn't anything useful. A PostgreSQL `timestamp` has a higher resolution than SQLite's `datetime`, that might be causing some grouping strangeness; try `group by m.date::date` and see what that does. And using `date` as a column name is almost criminal, you might want to have a few words with whoever is responsible for choosing the original column names.

Comment: idk if this helps, but i think what the query is trying to do is: 1. modify the date for each day to the end of the week (sunday) then group each of the counts by date. That way you are basically counting the total number of emails sent for the 7 day period.

Comment: Does your guess match what the SQLite version does? The date mangling in the SELECT is going back to the nearest Sunday. Is the SQLite version grouping by the `as date` date rather than the `m.date` date?